# Left join QueryBuilder Symfony 2

Tags: sql, symfony2, join, orm, doctrine

No consigo entender como hacer un `LEFT JOIN` usando `QueryBuilder` de symfony2, la consulta que necesito hacer es esta:

```
SELECT * FROM extranet.version_portal v 
LEFT JOIN extranet.version_portal_usuario vu 
ON vu.version_id = v.id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segun la doumentacion oficial:

```
$qb->select(array('v')) 
->from('version_portal', 'v')
$qb->leftJoin('u.version_id', 'vu', 'WITH', 'vu.id = 
v.id')
```